# SVN Update after modifying files locally but before committing

Tags: svn

I mistakenly did a svn update on a svn repository. It simply responded with:

```
Updating '.':
At revision 23
```

- I did not want to do this update.
- I am the only one who is using this SVN repository.
- I modified files locally without committing them.
- As there was no other output, is it safe to say that my currently edited files were not overwritten by the svn update? That I have not lost my edits?

I restored backup in a different directory and compared files and did not find that they were overwritten.

I read the SVN manual it refers to a line being displayed for each modified file and since I did not get any other messages, can I safely assume that my current editing was not overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

`svn update` has simply confirmed that your working copy is already "at revision 23".

Generally `svn update` will list every file that has been changed in the repository and merge the changes into your working copy. If a change conflicts with changes you are making, a conflict may occur and will need to be manually resolved.

Use `svn status` and `svn diff` to view the status of and modifications to the files you have edited.

---

In response to your comment:

`svn update` has not overwritten your modifications.

Even if new revisions had been pulled in (which they were not), the changes would be merged with your modifications. If those changes could not be merged, a conflict would result, and `svn status` would show a **C** against the filename instead of an **M**.

Comment: Are you confirming that doing an **svn update** has NOT overwritten modifications I have made locally in my folder? Thats the key question, obviously. When I do a **svn status**, I see a M next to files which have been added to Repo and ? for those which are not added to repo. **svn diff** lists a whole bunch of changes.